# Interacting with an existing terminal using Expect

Tags: expect

Is it possible to interact with an already existing terminal using *[Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)*?

Usually a process/terminal is launched via the *Expect* script, but I want to interact with a terminal that was opened **not** by the *Expect* script.

Answer (score 2):

Not without using other tools, like "screen", and attaching to the other shell.

An example of this:

```
$ screen bash
```

Now you could, from another teminal, attach to the same shell and do stuff, using this:

```
$ screen -x
```

So i guess your Expect could do the same, issuing "screen -x" and then doing stuff on the shell.